# How to draw in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have this code that draws a rectangle.

```
//// General Declarations
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//// Color Declarations
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.48 green: 0.833 blue: 0.38 alpha: 1];

//// Rectangle Drawing
CGRect rectangleRect = CGRectMake(58, 19, 85, 85);
UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: rectangleRect];
[color setFill];
[rectanglePath fill];
{
    NSString* textContent = @"hello";
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* rectangleStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
    rectangleStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSDictionary* rectangleFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size: 42.5], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: rectangleStyle};

    CGFloat rectangleTextHeight = [textContent boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(rectangleRect.size.width, INFINITY)  options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: rectangleFontAttributes context: nil].size.height;
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, rectangleRect);
    [textContent drawInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectangleRect), CGRectGetMinY(rectangleRect) + (CGRectGetHeight(rectangleRect) - rectangleTextHeight) / 2, CGRectGetWidth(rectangleRect), rectangleTextHeight) withAttributes: rectangleFontAttributes];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

The code works fine if place inside uiview subclass, but how can i use it inside the main viewcontroller without using any subclass?? can someone please convert the code to see how it can be used inside viewcontroller instead??

i can place UIBezierPath inside a shapelayer, but the last part with text i dont know how to do that. Please show me

Comment: You can't draw "in a view controller". A view controller is not a view. You need to do this inside a UIView.

Comment: My friend i'm able to convert the first part to CAShapeLayer without any problem. The only part i'm missing is the text..

Comment: By creating a CAShapeLayer you are creating a "visual object" (like a UIView) you're adding to your view controller. Did you take a look at CATextLayer?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will look into it

Comment: The question is not if you can do it but why you want to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make any sense. It's like asking how you get your computer to bake a cake.

You need to read up on the MVC design pattern.

A view controller is a controller object. It provides the logic that *controls* the display of a set of views, and mediates between the model (the data) and the view objects that make up the contents of a screen.

View controllers cannot and should not draw to the screen. They own and manage view objects that draw to the screen.

Under the covers, view objects render to the screen using layers. You can add layers to a view object and those layers will also be drawn. So yes, you can place a bezier path inside a shape layer and add that layer to a view, and that will cause the layer to be drawn as part of drawing the view.